# Non-resolvable import POM. Could not transfer artifact

Tags: maven, networking, configuration

I am setting up a Maven project (works fine on windows) on Mac. When I run Maven install (via Eclipse) on the project I get the below error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/americanexpress/javara/ra-components-jboss/6.0/ra-components-jboss-6.0.pom

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com. americanexpress. merchant. gms. grd: grdhomeui: 1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/ psivapr/ git/ grd-ui/ pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact com. americanexpress. javara: ra-components- jboss: pom: 6.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error @ line 23, column 16: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check your hosts file and DNS on the Mac workstation

The following error fragment:

```
unknown error @ line 23, column 16: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org
```

indicates that the `repo.maven.aphache.org` host is not being found on your Mac.

Check your hosts and DNS settings on the Mac, and make sure the site is reachable. There may be a network settings misconfiguration on your Mac that is not present on your Windows workstation.

Comment: That is right! Had to configure the proxy settings on my Mac to make the site accessible. Thanks. That worked!

Comment: @PoonkodiSivapragasam Great! Glad it worked ... if you have an opportunity, please upvote and accept the answer so anyone else who has the same problem can know how it was resolved.